# A matrix with array elements in c++

Tags: c++

I happened to need an n by n matrix, each of its elements is an integer array of length m. I was wondering what is the efficient method to create such matrix. By the way, I don't want to use the vectors here; I am interested to do this using c++ arrays. Furthermore, how I would be able to change the element of such matrix after creating one. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't use `int foo[n][n][m]`?

Comment: To change the size, you probably have to reallocate it. Otherwise, use the code @NathanOliver posted. If you want the sizes to not be constants, look into dynamically allocating on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C-style arrays:

```
int arr [n][n][m];
```

Using C++ arrays:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<int,n>,n>,m> arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own matrix type with C++ arrays (needs C++14):

```
template <unsigned N, unsigned M, typename T = int>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<std::array<T, N>, N>, M>;
```

And, to use it:

```
Matrix<10, 3> mat1;           // T = int
Matrix<10, 3, unsigned> mat2; // T = unsigned
```